# Explanation for following VBA regular expression?

Tags: regex, vba, excel

i have taken this regular expression from the internet itself

```
    RegExp.Pattern = "^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(\/)31)\1|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(\/)(?:29|30)\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:0?2(\/)29\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(\/)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$"
```

i just know only the basic details of the regular expression and not all the details
what i know is that it checks whether the date is in dd/mm/yyyy format or not and also whether the date is a leap year or not

also i don't know what's the meaning of ?:?: etc.

Can anyone please tell me the full meaning of this regular expression by explaining what does each character in the above regular expression means.

it would help me a lot in learning as i'm not able to understand most of the characters present in the regular expression

Comment: There are many web sites and tools available that help learning and analysing regex's.  My favorite is [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/)

Comment: i'll definitely give a try to this software, thanks for the help

Comment: i have used the software which you have mentioned and is a good software to learn and analyse the regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've picked a ghastly regex for learning purposes, that's for sure (and it does contain at least some warts, if not outright bugs, but I'm not going to debug this mess). One might argue that this is a good example for a problem that had better be solved using a different tool.

I suggest you read a [basic regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) first. Here are some pointers that should help you find the relevant topics there:

```
^      Start of string anchor
(?...) Non-capturing group
(...)  Capturing group
[...]  Character class
?      Quantifier (1 or 0 repetition of the previous token)
|      Alternation ("or")
\2     Backreference to the second capturing group
\d     Shorthand for digit
\/     (Unnecessary escape sequence, a simple / would work just fine)
$      End of string anchor
```